# Call function with variadic arguments where variadic arugments are references

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I try to implement a class which accepts a function and a variadic argument list as input to execute these functions later on a worker thread. My current implementation has a problem, if one of the arguments is a reference.

Have a look at the following smaller code example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Result, typename ...Args>
Result Foo(Result f(Args...), Args... args)
{
    return f(args...);
}

int BarValue(int x){return x;}
int BarPointer(int* x){ *x++;return *x; }
int BarRef(int& x){ x++; return x; }

int main()
{
    int x{0};
    std::cout << Foo(BarValue, x)           << std::endl;
    std::cout << Foo(BarPointer, &x)        << std::endl;
    std::cout << Foo(BarRef, x)             << std::endl; // does not compile: Error 1
    std::cout << Foo(BarRef, std::ref(x))   << std::endl; // does also not compile: Error 2
    return 0;
}
```

Error 1:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:31:31: error: no matching function for call to 'Foo(int (&)(int&), int&)'
   31 |     std::cout << Foo(BarRef, x)             << std::endl;
      |                               ^
<source>:4:8: note: candidate: 'template<class Result, class ... Args> Result Foo(Result (*)(Args ...), Args ...)'
    4 | Result Foo(Result f(Args...), Args... args)
      |        ^~~
<source>:4:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:31:31: note:   inconsistent parameter pack deduction with 'int&' and 'int'
   31 |     std::cout << Foo(BarRef, x)             << std::endl;
      |                               ^
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:31:31: error: no matching function for call to 'Foo(int (&)(int&), int&)'
   31 |     std::cout << Foo(BarRef, x)             << std::endl;
      |                               ^
<source>:4:8: note: candidate: 'template<class Result, class ... Args> Result Foo(Result (*)(Args ...), Args ...)'
    4 | Result Foo(Result f(Args...), Args... args)
      |        ^~~
<source>:4:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:31:31: note:   inconsistent parameter pack deduction with 'int&' and 'int'
   31 |     std::cout << Foo(BarRef, x)             << std::endl;
      |  

                         ^
```

Error 2:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:33:41: error: no matching function for call to 'Foo(int (&)(int&), std::reference_wrapper<int>)'
   33 |     std::cout << Foo(BarRef, std::ref(x))   << std::endl;
      |                                         ^
<source>:5:8: note: candidate: 'template<class Result, class ... Args> Result Foo(Result (*)(Args ...), Args ...)'
    5 | Result Foo(Result f(Args...), Args... args)
      |        ^~~
<source>:5:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:33:41: note:   inconsistent parameter pack deduction with 'int&' and 'std::reference_wrapper<int>'
   33 |     std::cout << Foo(BarRef, std::ref(x))   << std::endl;
      |                                         ^
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:33:41: error: no matching function for call to 'Foo(int (&)(int&), std::reference_wrapper<int>)'
   33 |     std::cout << Foo(BarRef, std::ref(x))   << std::endl;
      |                                         ^
<source>:5:8: note: candidate: 'template<class Result, class ... Args> Result Foo(Result (*)(Args ...), Args ...)'
    5 | Result Foo(Result f(Args...), Args... args)
      |        ^~~
<source>:5:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:33:41: note:   inconsistent parameter pack deduction with 'int&' and 'std::reference_wrapper<int>'
   33 |     std::cout << Foo(BarRef, std::ref(x))   << std::endl;
      |                                         ^
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

Compiled with `gcc 10.2` and -O3 `-std=c++17` : [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/aEM9c5dEP)

How can I solve this reference problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recommendation is that you take a look at how the standard library itself uses templates to pass callable objects (functions, lambdas, etc.): By using a single template type:

```
template<typename Func, typename ...Args>
auto Foo(Func f, Args&&... args)
{
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Note that I have added a call to [`std::forward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) to properly "forward" the arguments.

Also note that I made the return-type `auto` to let the compiler deduce the return type.

---

If I understand your comments correctly, you want to create a variable that holds the returned value of `f`, and then return that variable later? Then you could either do it using `decltype` as you do in your compiler-explorer link, or just use plain `auto` again when defining and initializing your variable:

```
template<typename Func, typename ...Args>
auto Foo(Func f, Args&&... args)
{
    auto value = f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    // Do something with the variable value...

    return value;
}
```

This will of course not work if the function `f` have a `void` return value.

Comment: How can I create a datatype which is deduced from auto to return later? Imagine the return and the call of f is not in the same scope. Is this the correct way: https://godbolt.org/z/dbWoq6Wdb?

Comment: No that is not what I meant. I want to create the type earlier to pass it into an lambda, where the value gets set. After that I have to do some clean-ups and return then the value set there, therefore I need to know the type

Comment: @RoQuOTriX You can use `decltype` like that yes, or again use `auto` type deduction (shown in my updated answer).

Comment: One last question, how to deal with void return type? Right now I implemented two methods, one with the decltype and one without

Comment: @RoQuOTriX It's not possible without having to write two functions anyway, but I think it should be possible to use some templates and template specialization to keep the interface clean for the callers of the functions at least.